# Best option for indexing 3 columns where only 2 columns are queried at a time in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

For the following scenario, what is the most efficient indexing? 3 columns:

`user_id, created_at, and name.`

((`user_id` and `created_at`) are queried together and (`user_id` and `name`) are queried together.

The `created_at` and `name` are exclusively used to sort. As an example:

`SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY created_at [["user_id", 1]]`

or

`SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY name [["user_id", 1]]`

I know that indexing is left to right so would two multi-column indexes on `"user_id, created_at"` and `"user_id, name"` be best or is there a way to "share" the user_id index (with something like 3 indexes on user_id, created_at, and name individually)?

Comment: You should show what sample conditions look like.  For instance, are they always equality?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added sample queries. The user_id is used for equality and the others (created_at and name) for ordering.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want separate indexes on user_id,  created_at and name?

Comment: No reason, just want to make sure I use the most efficient indexing space wise (want to avoid any unnecessary duplication). Using separate indexing on (user_id and created_at) and (user_id and name) seems to duplicate the user_id index so wanted to make sure that is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [bloom index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/bloom.html).

That can be used as a filter for queries containing an arbitrary subset of the indexed columns.

You will have to install the `bloom` contrib module.